# MySQL select and count in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table exactly like this

```
|month|year|candidate_id|emp_id
|    6|2016|10          |5
|    6|2016|11          |5
|    6|2016|12          |5
|    7|2016|13          |5
|    7|2016|14          |5
```

So I want to count how many candidates were added each month and display month, year and total candidates just like below

```
|Month|Year|Total
|    6|2016|3
|    7|2016|2
```

I tried using this sql script

```
SELECT
    c.MONTH,
    c.YEAR,
    a.total
FROM
    wp_tsf_reports c,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) total
        FROM wp_tsf_reports b
        WHERE b.emp_id = '5'
        GROUP BY b.MONTH, b.YEAR DESC
    ) a
WHERE
    c.emp_id = '5'
GROUP BY c.MONTH, c.YEAR DESC
```

The output of this is

```
|Month|Year|Total
|    6|2016|3
|    7|2016|3
```

As you can see its showing 3 two times where total should be 3 for the 6th month and 2 for the 7th month.

Any help is appriciated

Comment: select month, year, count(1) as total_count from where empid=5 table
group by month,year;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
select month, year, count(*) as total from table
where empid=5
group by month,year
```

Comment: Woks as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use any complex or sub query, this can achieved using single query

```
select month, year, count(1) total from wp_tsf_reports
where empid = 5
group by month,year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below query, you will get the desired output.

```
SELECT 
month,
year,
count(*) as total 
FROM table_name 
where emp_id='5' 
group by month,year
```

Answer (score 0):

simple query like this

```
select count(*),month,year  from report group by month having count(*) > 1;
```

the results

```
+----------+-------+------+
| count(*) | month | year |
+----------+-------+------+
|        3 |     6 | 2016 |
|        2 |     7 | 2016 |
+----------+-------+------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to explain the original query (the accepted solution is perfect to fix the issue).

|Month|Year|Total
|    6|2016|3
|    7|2016|2
I tried using this sql script

You sub query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
FROM wp_tsf_reports b
WHERE b.emp_id = '5'
GROUP BY b.MONTH, b.YEAR DESC
```

This will return 2 rows:-

```
Total
3
2
```

You then cross join that with the wp_tsf_reports table, giving (temporarily):-

```
|month|year|candidate_id|emp_id|total
|    6|2016|10          |5     |3
|    6|2016|10          |5     |2
|    6|2016|11          |5     |3
|    6|2016|11          |5     |2
|    6|2016|12          |5     |3
|    6|2016|12          |5     |2
|    7|2016|13          |5     |3
|    7|2016|13          |5     |2
|    7|2016|14          |5     |3
|    7|2016|14          |5     |2
```

You haven't returned the month and year from the sub query, nor specified to join based on the month / year, hence the cross join which gives you every combination of rows from the table and from the sub query.

The GROUP BY is then picking the values (ie, the value of the total column) from 1 row for each month / year. Which rows value that MySQL picks to use is unspecified. It could be the 3 or the 2, or could even vary.

Hence you get:-

```
|Month|Year|Total
|    6|2016|3
|    7|2016|3
```

but equally you could get

```
|Month|Year|Total
|    6|2016|2
|    7|2016|2
```